# What is the use of a rectified linear function in a basic neural network

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, mnist

I have been playing around with neural networks and their uses in applications lately. Just recently, I came across a tutorial describing a neural network that would learn how to classify handwritten numbers from 0-9 (MNIST). The portion of code from the tutorial that I'm having trouble with is below(https://pythonprogramming.net/tensorflow-neural-network-session-machine-learning-tutorial/)

```
def neural_network_model(data):
    hidden_1_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([784, nodes_hl1])),
                'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_hl1]))}

    hidden_2_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_hl1, nodes_hl2])),
                'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_hl2]))}

    hidden_3_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_hl2, nodes_hl3])),
                'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_hl3]))}

    output_layer = {'weights':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([nodes_hl3, n_classes])),
                'biases':tf.Variable(tf.random_normal([n_classes])),}


    l1 = tf.add(tf.matmul(data,hidden_1_layer['weights']), hidden_1_layer['biases'])
    l1 = tf.nn.relu(l1)

    l2 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l1,hidden_2_layer['weights']), hidden_2_layer['biases'])
    l2 = tf.nn.relu(l2)

    l3 = tf.add(tf.matmul(l2,hidden_3_layer['weights']), hidden_3_layer['biases'])
    l3 = tf.nn.relu(l3)

    output = tf.matmul(l3,output_layer['weights']) + output_layer['biases']

    return output
```

I have a basic grasp of what is going on. The 3 hidden layers are each a set of nodes which are connected by biases and weights. The final output layer is the result of the neural network. I understand everything here, except the lines of code that include tf.nn.relu(). After looking at TensorFlow's documentation, all it mentions is that the function computes the rectified linear of features(https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/nn/activation_functions_#relu). I am rather confused as to what this function is performing, and what significance it has in the neural network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

some of the advantages of relu(rectified linear units are)

- Less computationally expensive(and hence , better performance)
- Some other functions like sigmoid tend to satturate
- They have derivates that are easy to calc(remember the training process relies in derivates)

Please check this https://www.quora.com/What-are-the-benefits-of-using-rectified-linear-units-vs-the-typical-sigmoid-activation-function